# Combining matrices in set according to non-NA columns

Tags: r, list, matrix, bind

We start with a set of matrices. Referring to all matrices in the set, i want to create a new matrix, that represents a combination of the columns of each matrix in the set.

Each matrix in the set has a different number of rows. when we combine matrices, new rows should be filled with NA. The new matrix takes the first 3 non-NA columns of each matrix in the set and joins them.

setup

```
set.seed(4)
mat1 <- matrix(nrow =9, ncol=9, runif(81))
mat2 <- matrix(nrow=10, ncol =9, runif(90))
mat3 <- matrix(nrow=11, ncol =9, runif(99))
mat4 <- matrix(nrow =9, ncol=9, runif(81)) 
mat2[,1:3] <- NA
mat3[,1:5] <- NA
mat4[,1:4] <- NA
mat_set <- list(mat1,mat2,mat3, mat4)
```

new matrix:

bind:

```
mat1[,1:3], mat2[,6:9], mat3[,6:9], mat4[,5:8]
```

i want the new matrix to have the same number of rows as the largest matrix in the set (in this case nrow =11). When row of matrix in the set not equal to 11, fill their entries with NA. so for Mat1, make rows 10 and 11, which do not exist at the moment, equal to NA for all columns. This step must occur before binding the matrices together.

Output form:
Ideally, i'd like the code to automatically detect the NA columns for matrices in the set, and then join the FIRST 3 Non-NA columns. Also if it could work on a large set of matrices/ data.frames that'd be great. thanks!

output should be of the form:

```
cbind.fill(mat1[,1:3], mat2[,7:9], mat3[,7:9], mat4[,7:9], fill= NA)
```

but should not have to manually type out each matrix in the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `lapply` to loop over list of matrices and select the first 3 columns with non-NA values and use `do.call` to apply `cbind.fill` to the list.

```
do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(lapply(mat_set, function(x) 
        x[, head(which(apply(!is.na(x), 2, any)), 3)]), fill = NA))
```

Or another way to get non-NA columns using `colSums`

```
do.call(rowr::cbind.fill, c(lapply(mat_set, function(x) 
     x[, head(which(colSums(is.na(x)) != nrow(x)), 3)]), fill = NA))
```